# Integration test user authentication redirect, get all paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise to manage authentication in my Rails 4 application. Users can only access other pages in my application once they are logged in. I would like to write an integration test for that functionality.

Something in these lines:

```
should 'redirect to sign in page if user is not signed in' do
    all_paths.each do |path|
     get_via_redirect path
     assert_response :success
     assert_equal '/users/sign_in', path 
    end
end
```

How do I get all paths/urls in Rails and does the way I am attempting to test this functionality make sense?